# Is there a way to take a data frame with columns as time and rows as dates and convert into vector with date/time combined?

Tags: r, datetime, time-series, reshape, tidyr

My data set is pollutant concentration at a specific monitoring site, where the row names are the date of observation, and the column names are the time of observation. I.e. the data is a n x 25 matrix where each column corresponds to a one hour time period and each row represents all the measurements on a given date.

See example below:

```
Day          0:00-1:00    1:00-2:00    2:00-3:00    3:00-4:00   4:00-5:00   5:00-6:00    ...
01/20/2019   0.045        0.258        0.335        0.347       0.255       0.198
01/21/2019   0.058        0.125        0.187        0.177       0.278       0.389
.
.
.
```

(Note that the real data would have 25 columns to have all 24 hours accounted for)

I'm trying to run some time series analysis on this data and as far as I can tell the base ts() function is not equipped to handle data presented in this format, as it interprets each column as a separate time series.

Is there a way I could condense this data such that each value has only a corresponding row name which has both date and time i.e.

```
Date/Time:               Concentration
01/20/2019-0:00-1:00     0.045
01/20/2019-1:00-2:00     0.258
```

I've tried briefly using tidyr, specifically the "gather" and "unite" functions but didn't have any success with them.

Is there a way I can easily condense this data frame or another way to analyze this data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `gather` function is on the right track, and instead of `unite`, you'll actually want `separate`. You might also need stuff from the `lubridate` package to convert the dates and times. (The syntax for `gather` can be strange for folks, and the new `pivot_longer` function does the same work if you find that easier.)

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
df %>%
  mutate(Day = mdy(Day)) %>%
  gather(key = "time_block", value = "Concentration", -Day) %>%
  separate(time_block, into = c("from", "to"), sep = "-", remove = FALSE) %>%
  # Hopefully times are on a 24-hour clock, else you have more work to do
  mutate(timestamp_string = paste0(as.character(Day), " ", from)) %>%
  mutate(timestamp_dt = ymd_hm(timestamp_string))
```

Output will end up looking like this.

```
         Day time_block from   to Concentration timestamp_string        timestamp_dt
1  2019-01-20  0:00-1:00 0:00 1:00         0.045  2019-01-20 0:00 2019-01-20 00:00:00
2  2019-01-21  0:00-1:00 0:00 1:00         0.058  2019-01-21 0:00 2019-01-21 00:00:00
3  2019-01-20  1:00-2:00 1:00 2:00         0.258  2019-01-20 1:00 2019-01-20 01:00:00
4  2019-01-21  1:00-2:00 1:00 2:00         0.125  2019-01-21 1:00 2019-01-21 01:00:00
```

Comment: Thanks, that is definitely working in regards to getting the rows/columns gathered. I'm still playing around with the data slightly, but it appears to have done the trick. Would the `pivot_longer` function take a similar argument input as your method?

Comment: The `pivot_longer` function can do a bit more, and takes clearer arguments. Looks like Zhiquang Wang has laid out an example answer, and there's more documentation here: https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/dev/articles/pivot.html. The `gather`, `spread` combination are staying around, but the idea is that the `pivot_` functions will be the ones that folks are slowly moving towards.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `pivot_longer`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
 pivot_longer(-Day, names_to = "time", values_to = "value") %>% 
  mutate(day_time = lubridate::mdy_hm(paste(Day, sub("X", "", time))))
```

If your data format is like this:

```
df <-data.frame(
  Day = c("01/20/2019", "01/21/2019"), 
  `0:00` = c(0.045, 0.058), 
  `1:00` = c(0.258, 0.125),  
  `2:00` = c(0.335, 0.187),  
  `3:00` = c(0.347, 0.177),  
  `4:00` = c(0.255, 0.275),  
  `5:00` = c(0.198, 0.389))
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try (did not run the code)

```
library(reshape)
yournewdata<-melt(data=yourdata, id.vars=Day)
```

For the times: in your example, your times are not given in a format that is compatible with R date formats. (There are no time ranges in R). So your data should be converted to hours. I would do it by renaming the columns before doing the melt operation.

colnames(mydata)<-c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, .....)

Before you convert these to time values you should change them from a factor to numeric value.